# How to start another action in a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Someone put this script on the net to check a website for event tickets.  How can I modify it to start iTunes playing with osascript or play a system beep, etc. when this_year_count > 1?  Can I send an SMS from this script?

```
    # !/bin/sh
    #
    # ABCD 2013 checking script

    CURL='curl'
    ABCD__SUPER_SECRET="uggcf://qrirybcre.nccyr.pbz/jjqp/"
    CURL_OPTIONS='--silent'
    $CURL $CURL_OPTIONS `echo -n $ABCD__SUPER_SECRET | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'` | \

    sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]*/\
    /g' | awk ' BEGIN { this_year_count = 0 }
    /2013/ { this_year_occurrences[NR] }
    !/2013/ { ++not_abcd_count }
    END { for (line in this_year_occurrences) {
    ++this_year_count
    }
    if(this_year_count > 1)
    print "Hey, you might want to consider seeing if you can order tickets."
    else
    print "Run this checker again when you are ready to check things again"
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I'll short answer/long answer this:

short answers:
How can I modify it to start iTunes playing with osascript or play a system beep, etc. when this_year_count > 1?

replace

> print "Hey, you might want to consider seeing if you can order tickets."

with your call/beep

Can I send an SMS from this script?

You could If you had some way to send SMS messages in another file you could import. I.e. its possible, but nothing in this script AS IS, allows you to do so.

Long answers:
replace

> print "Hey, you might want to consider seeing if you can order tickets."

with

> osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\" to activate"

for itunes

or

> sudo apt-get beep

or

> sudo apt-get mpg123

to beep (works on my system but i'm not using a mac, you'll need to check that one)

As for sending an SMS

> [How do I send an SMS from a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043490/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-a-shell)

will see you right

Comment: I've already tried replacing the print statement with ones for beeps and iTunes startup.  They don't work in this script for some reason.  Nothing happens as if the commands weren't there.  I created a new script with only the beep and osascript commands and it worked fine.  Any other suggestions?  Can someone copy this script and add solutions  to it to and repost after you see that it works?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i just googled the script. http://blog.agilebits.com/2013/04/01/1password-4-mac-wwdc-april-fools/

check the date and title. If you posted this as a joke, I'll admit I fell for it but considering it was posted on the second of April, not the first, a little late.

If it was an honest question, then discard this script, it does not do what you wanted it to do.