# Is it possible to send Sms from android phone using adb protocol

Tags: android, adb, usb4java, android-host-api

I want to send SMS from android phone connecting to my computer using USB. I am suing usb4Java library. I have accessed the phone and send adb commands to phone according to the link [usb4java-javax-examples](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-javax-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/javax/examples). Here is the code and output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ....
    AdbDevice device = devices.get(0);
    device.open();
    try {
        // Send the connect message
        Message message = new ConnectMessage(ConnectMessage.SYSTEM_TYPE_HOST, "12345678", "ADB Demo");
        System.out.println("Sending: " + message);
        device.sendMessage(message);
        boolean connected = false;
        while (!connected) {
            message = device.receiveMessage();
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);

            // If connect message has been received then we are finished
            if (message instanceof ConnectMessage) {
                connected = true;
            }
            ....
        } // end of while
        // Open "sync:"
        message = new OpenMessage(1, "sync:");
        System.out.println("Sending: " + message);
        device.sendMessage(message);
        message = device.receiveMessage();
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);
        if (!(message instanceof OkayMessage)) {
            System.err.println("Open failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int remoteId = ((OkayMessage) message).getRemoteId();

        // Close
        message = new CloseMessage(1, remoteId);
        System.out.println("Sending: " + message);
        device.sendMessage(message);
        message = device.receiveMessage();
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);    
    }
}
```

Here is the output that I received

```
Sending: CONNECT(0x01000000, 4096, "host:12345678:ADB Demo")
Received: CONNECT(0x01000000, 4096, "device::")
Sending: OPEN(1, "sync:")
Received: OKAY(1, 1)
Sending: CLOSE(1, 1)
Received: CLOSE(0, 1)
```

Is there any way that I send Sms command to android phone using Adb protpcol and sms has been send. Like `SENDSMS(int number, String textMessage)`.

Or is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks

**Edit

---

Here What I am doing but I am getting CLOSE(0, 1). Don't know what is doing wrong

```
message = new OpenMessage(1, "shell:command");
System.out.println("Sending: " + message);
device.sendMessage(message);
message = device.receiveMessage();
System.out.println("Received: " + message);
if (!(message instanceof OkayMessage)) {
    System.err.println("Open failed");
    System.exit(1);
}
int remoteId = ((OkayMessage) message).getRemoteId();
int localId = ((OkayMessage) message).getLocalId();

String num = "00923424700007";
String text = "Hello World";

message = new WriteMessage(remoteId, localId, "am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:"+num+" --es sms_body \""+text+"\" --ez exit_on_sent true");
System.out.println("Sending: " + message);
device.sendMessage(message);
message = device.receiveMessage();
System.out.println("Received: " + message);

if (!(message instanceof OkayMessage)) {
    System.err.println("Open failed");
    System.exit(1);
}

remoteId = ((OkayMessage) message).getRemoteId();
localId = ((OkayMessage) message).getLocalId();
```

What I am doing wrong at line

```
message = new WriteMessage(remoteId, localId, "am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:"+num+" --es sms_body \""+text+"\" --ez exit_on_sent true");
```

Thanks

Comment: A telefone number is not an `int`: for example `0033 ...`. You need to use a String to represent it.

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/q/4043490/244611

Answer (score 2):

Try with this :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

See [the entire answer by arpz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043490/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-a-shell).

Comment: the proper way to link to an existing answer is by flagging the new question as duplicate

Comment: Do I send it like this `message = new OpenMessage(1, "android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:923424700007 --es sms_body \"SMS BODY GOES HERE\" --ez exit_on_sent true");`  . I also tried the whole command that you provided but I am getting `Received: CLOSE(0, 1)`. Thanks