# Send SMS from Linux Terminal using adb bridge on Android Phone

Tags: android, shell, sms, adb

I tried to follow [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580199/sending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb) and also [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043490/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-a-shell). Unfortunately, I receive the following:

```
$ adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "1234564789" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "SMS TEXT HERE"
```

*service: unknown option TEXT*

*Result: Parcel(a Copying message to Icc: Neither user  2000 nor current process has android permission  RECEIVE SMS)*

```
$ adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "+1234564789" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "SMS TEXT HERE"
```

*service: unknown option TEXT*

*Result: Parcel(a Copying message to Icc: Neither user  2000 nor current process has android permission  RECEIVE SMS)*

```
$ adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+1234564789" s16 "null" s16 "keje" s16 "null" s16 0
```

*Result: Parcel(Attempt to get length of null array)*

```
$adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+1234564789" s16 0 s16 "Hey you !" s16 0 s16 0
```

*Result: Parcel(Attempt to get length of null array)*

```
$adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234564789" s16 "+61418706275" s16 "Hey you !" i32 0 i32 0
```

*Result: Parcel(Attempt to get length of null array)*

I tried different combinations of the above, but I am unable to understand how others are able to send SMS using the command but I cannot.
I'll appreciate if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

I am using a linux machine and an android phone with 5.1 connected with USB cable with USB debugging ON.

```
ro.build.version.release=5.1
TAG=android-5.1.0_r1
```

Answer (score 2):

At last I found out how it should work on Android 5.1.

```
$ adb shell service call isms 9 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "DEST_NUMBER" s16 "null" s16 "MESSAGE\ BODY" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

You can also use the following format to compensate for spaces in the message:

```
$ adb shell service call isms 9 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "DEST_NUMBER" s16 "null" s16 "'MESSAGEBODY 2 with spaces'" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

This query is now closed.

Comment: May I ask: should this work on a terminal emulator, like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm ? The result so far is parcel (0000 '...')

Comment: Another question: where do I find my phone number ? Does it need country code ? Area code ?